# Is the supremum of continuous affine functions continuous in its effective domain?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $\mathcal{A}$ be a non-empty set of real-valued continuous affine (or maybe convex) functions. Is it true that the function $\sup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A(x)$ is continuous in its effective domain? I know it is not true without the "affine (or maybe convex)" assumption. Thanks!

Comment: If each function in the family $\mathcal{A}$ is convex, so too is $x\mapsto\sup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A(x)$ (check). Therefore, if $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the desired result follows since a convex function is continuous on open sets.

Comment: Do you need a result for more general spaces?

Comment: Yes. I need a result for arbitrary topological vector spaces.

Comment: Certainly you must at least have some assumptions on the scalar field of $X$ (i.e., is it $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: Yes I am assuming $X$ is a real vector space.